# log4net items not shown in AppServiceAppLogs

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics, log4net-configuration, azure-diagnostics, azure-monitor

We are using log4net for our application logging in azure.
We configured it according to this [document](https://azure.github.io/AppService/2020/08/31/AzMon-AppServiceAppLogs.html) , the logs are stored in

```
d:/home/LogFiles/Application/Log4netfile-[%processid].txt
```

we can download the files from https://xxxx.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/dump and I can also see them in Log stream, there it looks like this

```
2022-02-06T18:22:57  PID[29616] Verbose     log4net: Adding appender named [FileAppender] to logger [root].
2022-02-06T18:22:57  PID[29616] Verbose     log4net: Hierarchy Threshold []
2022-02-06T18:22:58  PID[29616] Verbose     LOG4NET Fatal LOG4NET LOG4NET
2022-02-06T18:22:58  PID[29616] Verbose     LOG4NET Debug Message Message
```

Line  items like:

```
log4net: Adding appender named
```

are created by log4net during internal setup (using debug=true), and those show up in our AppServiceAppLogs,  however, items which are genereted by the logger using:

```
Logger.Fatal("LOG4NET Fatal LOG4NET LOG4NET");
```

are visible in stream and files but they are  not showing up in AppServiceLogs.

I tried multiple different appenders the only one which shows up in Log-Streams and in files is FileAppender (or RollingFileAppender), all others are not showing in LogStreams or (as expected) in the files.

Based on this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-diagnostic-logs#send-logs-to-azure-monitor I assume that everything writen to the files should be than sent to azure-monitor - but in our case this is not hapening. Could you provide some reference about implementation / code how the sending of the files is done, and which process does that ?

I am wandering is there anything which we could configure differently to get the log-items to end up in AppServiceLogs? Or should we use some other appender?

I am aware of the issue in AspNetTraceAppender and I am trying to avoid implementation of new appender.

Answer (score -1):

There are a few things you can look into:

Call log4net configure before writing to your log file (only once is enough):

```
log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator();
```

or

```
log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
```

and then you can add flushing to your configuration:

```
<appender name="AzureTraceAppender" type="log4net.Appender.TraceAppender">
  <param name="ImmediateFlush" value="true" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <!-- can be any pattern you like -->
    <conversionPattern value="%logger - %message" />
  </layout>
</appender>
```

Immediately, this will flush the message.

In Global.asax, To make log4net read your configuration.

```cs
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    // Code that runs on application startup

    // Initialize log4net.
    log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
}
```

Make sure Azure Diagnostics has configured to all information needed for debugging.

After that, you can enable internal log4net debugging. Refer [internal debugging on this log4net faq page](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/faq.html). Standard it should log to your listener you have configured. To the trace element Add the autoflush="true" option . Or find directory on the worker role you can write to and access to read your logs.

Comment: hi, log4net is configured and the data is written to the files, so my log4net part is working, and I tried to explain it as good as I could in the answer. I can see the content of the files and download them (dump), but they do not get pushed to Azure Monitoring Tables - any Idea how to resolve that problem or at least find the root cuase